# Unit tests fail with error "Cypress command timeout of '4000ms' exceeded."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, cypress, react-testing-library

I am using cypress and react-testing library in order to execute unit tests on my component. However, I am running into the the below error when the test executes

"Cypress command timeout of '4000ms' exceeded."

I notice that the actual test that I have written succeeds. But there is an error in an "after all" hook that is somehow inserted. I do not have an "after all" hook in my test spec. I wanted to know where this could be invoked from since I do not have it in my code.

Additional Info: I am using webpack and istanbul plugins that are added in the plugins/index.js file

test-spec.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render, fireEvent, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import Greeting from '../../src/utils/testUtils/components/Greeting';

describe('react-testing-library', () => {   

    it('renders View Details component', () => {      
            const component = render(<Greeting />);
            component.getByText('Hello');
        })
})
```

My component - greeting.js

```js
import React from 'react';

export default function Greeting() {
    return (
        <div>{'Hello'}</div>
    );
}
```

cypress\support\index.js

```js
import './commands';
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support';
```

cypress\plugins\index.js

```js
const webpack = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')
const webpackOptions = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', 'istanbul'],
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}

const options = {
  // send in the options from your webpack.config.js, so it works the same
  // as your app's code
  webpackOptions,
  watchOptions: {}
}

module.exports = on => {
  on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options))
  on('task', require('@cypress/code-coverage/task'))

}
```

Below is the error that I get on the console

```
react-testing-library
    √ renders View Details component (68ms)
    1) "after each" hook for "renders View Details component"


  1 passing (7s)
  1 failing

  1) react-testing-library "after each" hook for "renders View Details component":
     Error: Cypress command timeout of '4000ms' exceeded.

Because this error occurred during a 'after each' hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.
      at http://localhost:4444/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:82978:25
```

Because of this the tests fail. Any suggestions as to why this error could be happening would greatly help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from the cypress community, it seems as though the react-testing-library is adding the after each hook for clean up.

https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/master/src/index.js

This is an async method which results in cypress giving a warning :

```
cypress_runner.js:85235 Cypress Warning: Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a test, but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise.
```

I was able to prevent this addition of the afterEach and get the tests working. We can use any one of the methods given [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#skipping-auto-cleanup) to achieve this.